# PHP’s DateTime constructor doesn’t understand the datetime format when it has a millisecond part & AM/PM together?

Tags: php

Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2023-09-17 11:32:30.626 AM) at position 24 (A): The timezone could not be found in the database"

I get this error when I try to create a DateTime object in PHP with the datetime string "2023-09-17 11:32:30.626 AM".

It does create a DateTime object with "2023-09-17 11:32:30 AM" and "2023-09-17 11:32:30.626" successfully, though. So it fails when the format is with a microsecond part & AM/PM (without timezone perhaps).

Before I start coding for converting the format, does anyone suggest a simpler solution for this? Like DateTime in C# has a method called ParseExact() and it accepts a specific format other than the default formats.

Comment: Because it's running through a pre-set list of formats, and that's not one of them. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat

Comment: Right. My question is how I can handle the format I mentioned. Like DateTime in C# has a method called ParseExact() and it accepts a specific format other than the default formats.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not benefit from a new DateTime question every time someone wants to parse a slightly non-standard datetime string.  Become acquainted with the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Related date parsing pages: [Adapt a date string into another format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23339368/2943403) and [Converting string to Date and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6238992/2943403) and [Unix Timestamp from custom string php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36065963/2943403) and many, many more.

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot change the format of the incoming text, then you'll want to use:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s.u a', $dateString);
```

Which will tell DateTime explicitly the format you're passing to it.

When you enter time into DateTime without explicitly defining the format, it accepts a wide range of standardized (RFC/ISO) and human-readable timestamps. If you want to include microseconds, you'll need to use the RFC3339_EXTENDED format, which looks like the following:

```
new DateTime("2023-09-17T11:32:30.626+00:00")
```

You can view the entire list of of supported formats at:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php

Comment: I'm not the one who is sending the datetime format. It comes from outside and I need to accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not confirm to any known RFC or IOS datetime standard, but that is okay, you can use the following method instead:

$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s.u a', $dateString);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) in this case to define whatever format you are receiving.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.v A', '2023-09-17 11:32:30.626 AM')
```

e.g.

```
$string = '2023-09-17 11:32:30.626 AM';
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.v A';
$dt     = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $string);
echo $dt->format(DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED);
```

> ```
> 2023-09-17T11:32:30.626-04:00
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up is because the format "2023-09-17 11:32:30.626 AM" is not a recognized format for creating a DateTime object in PHP because the milliseconds and AM/PM markers are included.

You can filter the string to remove the milliseconds and then convert it to a 24-hour format. Here's a suggestion:

```
$dateString = "2023-09-17 11:32:30.626 AM";

// Remove the milliseconds and AM/PM
$dateString = preg_replace('/\.\d+\s(AM|PM)/', ' $1', $dateString);

// Create a DateTime object
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s A', $dateString);

if ($dateTime === false) {
    echo "Failed to parse the date string.";
} else {
    echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Output in 24-hour format
}
```

Comment: We need microseconds and we can't remove them. I already got a solution, anyway. It's DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.v A').

Comment: I do not recommend regex for this task, but `\.\d+\s([PA]M)`.  Or more simply, just match `/\.\d{3}/` and replace with an empty string.

Comment: [`substr_replace($dateString, '', 19, 4)`](https://3v4l.org/JCYEV) will also do.